# Converting items in a text file to a <String, Long> HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm currently working on an assignment for school relating to HashMap and its associated functions. At the moment, we are using it to sort countries by population and landmass, using values from a .txt file. The problem I have is getting the items into a  HashMap from the text file. I'm using repl.it as my software because I'm working on my School-issued Chromebook. I'm not looking for a free answer, I'm simply looking for a push in the right direction so that I can get this assignment done.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
String input = reader.nextLine();
String parts[] = input.split("###");
Map<String, Long> CountryPop = new HashMap<String, Long>();
Map<String, Long> CountrySize = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

The idea is that the program takes the data from the text file and places relevant information in the respective HashMap. So, CountryPop receives country name and population number, CountrySize receives country name and land size number, with each piece of information split by ### (e.g. China###1420062022###9388211; This would read in CountryPop as China, 1420062022 and in CountrySize as China, 9388211). The issue is using one command to assign two different data types into the HashMap

At the moment I will continue working to find a solution, and if I find it on my own, I will delete the question altogether.

Comment: Please post relevant code here and not in external links. It's not clear from the question what exactly you want to put on the map - what's key, what's value?

Answer (score 0):

The `parts` array will contain the individual data items as `String`s.

The country name is at `parts [0]`, population and size at 1 and 2, respectively. Those you need to translate into a `Long`; you can use `Long.parseLong()` for that.

Then you have all data you need to put into the maps.

Note: it would be better to create a `class Country` with fields for name, population and size. Then you only need either a `List<Country>` or maybe a `Map <String <String, Country>` if you really need to access by name. That map can easily be created from the list though.